# MSBuild - want to get the output assembly

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a **.targets file** in a **folder named .pack** I have this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TaskAssembly>$(OutputPath)netstandard2.1\Test.dll</TaskAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Why instead of `MyProject\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\MyProject.dll` it locates like the below line?

```
MyProject\.pack\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\MyProject.dll
```

Why **.pack** is there!?

Then wanted to use it with a **Using task**

```
  <UsingTask
    TaskName="brand.ProBuild.Tasks.TestFunction"
    AssemblyFile="$(TaskAssembly)" 
    />
```

Defined as inline address, played with slashes, cleared bin/obj, restarted, don't why it can't understand some addresses.

Defined and used several path variables in my targets files, some working correctly and some are troublesome especially when want to use parents or some problems with slashes '/', don't know maybe some addresses are working randomly. But what is wrong with the $(OutputPath) ?!

Visual-studio 2019, .Net Standard 2.1 (It has multiple targets I want to get that specific dll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check in your main project, **before** the import node like `<Import Project=".pack\xxx.targets" />`, check whether you defined the **outputpath** property again like

```
<outputpath>.pack\bin\Debug\</outputpath>
```

**Suggestion**

From your description, you created a custom MSBuild task dll to use its new custom task in another project, **first**, please make sure that the `Test.dll` is in the output folder of  your project called `MyProject`.

**Then**, check whether you have redefined the **outputpath** before the **import** xml node.

Like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<outputpath>.pack\bin\Debug\</outputpath>
</PropertyGroup>
..........

<Import Project=".pack\xxx.targets" />

........

<UsingTask
    TaskName="brand.ProBuild.Tasks.TestFunction"
    AssemblyFile="$(TaskAssembly)" 
    />
```

**If** so, you should change OutputPath to `bin\Debug\`.

In addition, if it does not help you, please share the `xxx.csproj` of project **MyProject** with us so that we can troubleshoot your issue more quickly.

**Update 1**

Since you have only one targets file in your project, I suggest you could follow these suggestions:

**1)** close VS Instance, enter your project folder, delete the `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Then ,restart your project to test again.

**2)** you can define the correct value in the `xxx.csproj` file before the imports xml node to force the correct value of outputPath.

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  .......
  <Import Project="xxx.targets"/>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for trying to help, asked the question 2,3 days ago, so tried other approach, btw still eager to know the result of the code you provided, a bit busy with other tasks today, may provide feedback with a bit of delay. But at first glance I may have 2 questions: 1.  I don't want the output be placed in the .pack folder, isn't it strange?  The way MSBuild behaves on it, or I am missed something? 2. never used a variable this way to address the root of my project, really it can understand MyProject\bin\Debug\ ? Thanks for the answer, hope will back to this topic soon. +1

Comment: Oh, seems you blame me for defining the outputpath this way in any part of my program, no I didn't define the known property, just tried to use it. The program also is a simple one, and I guess about that project I didn't want to run it on my target assemblies, wanted to use in the current assembly and imported it as well, but was getting that strange output path.

Comment: I have only 1 targets file, and didn't define it anywhere, will upload the project at the first possible time, will check everything again, re-read your answer, try and test anything possible, then upload the project and will back to you. BTW It will be delay on the posts here.

Comment: If you create a new console project, did you get the same outputpath value as before? If the new project does not get the same thing, you can try these:  1) close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin`, `obj` folder and then restart project again. 2) or just define the normal outputpath value before  the import xml node.  `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>


<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>`